# Render graph in Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, graph, canvas, render

I am looking for libraries that can render graphs, PRETTY graphs.

I need to both render static images, preferably with python, and also to render them dynamically in the browser. A Canvas solution would be great, flash is acceptable too.

I googled around a little and found python-graph, but the images look quite ugly.

To clarify: I'm talking about graphs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), not charts.

Comment: http://thejit.org/ check this one out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out following:

- [canviz](http://code.google.com/p/canviz/) - Graphviz graphs in JS
- [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) - Graphviz for Python
- [yapgvb](http://code.google.com/p/yapgvb/) - Another alternative for Python

You should be able to use the same graph definition both in Python and JS. I hope those help. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), a port of the [Processing language](http://processing.org/), is a very powerful JavaScript visualization library that can been used to generate graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/), though the quality of the graphics might not be up to snuff.  What about invoking [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) in your webapp?  Not sure if people have done mathematical graphs, but the output certainly looks nice.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We use [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for the Internet Archives Open Library project and it works great. You can see a few of the graphs it's generated on the [OpenLibrary front page](http://openlibrary.org).